# Retaining an Assigned Instance Variable Property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory, memory-management

I have a property that has `(nonatomic, assign)` as attributes.

In a method, I then am `retaining` that variable then `releasing` it a line after.

Static analyzer is giving warning that `incorrect decrement of the reference count of object...`.

Can I not do this

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) Class *iVar;

            [self.iVar retain];
            [self.iVar removeFromSuperview];
            [self insertSubview:self.iVar atIndex:self.iVar.index];
            [self.iVar release];
```

Comment: Post a code example of what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the retain and release both happen in the same method, you might want to copy the property to a local variable and then work with that:

```
UIView *someView = self.interestingView;
[someView retain];
//...do some stuff...
[someView release];
```

That at least provides some protection in case the "some stuff" part happens to modify `self.interestingView`. And it'll probably satisfy the static analyzer, too.

In general, I would avoid retaining/releasing variables that back properties outside the accessors for those properties, except for a few well defined situations such as `-dealloc`. Similarly, avoid directly retaining/releasing the result of a property access, as in `[self.foo retain]`. If that property is changed before you get to the release, you end up with both a leak and, later, an over-release.

Comment: Good answer; the temp variable makes what's happening much clearer. It's also usually a bad idea to send `release` to the result of a property access. IOW, only manage ivar memory inside the accessor methods (and `init`/`dealloc`).

Comment: @JoshCaswell I agree, and I'll add that. Either use properties to manage memory or do it yourself, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that you're not working with a variable; you're working with the result of a property accessor. Each time you access the property, the static analyzer applies the normal memory management rules for an object returned from a method — namely, you shouldn't be releasing it. If you change it to use an actual local or instance variable, the warning will go away.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested a similar example,

You will appease the static analyzer by not using property notation

```
[iVar retain];
[self.iVar removeFromSuperview];
[self insertSubview:self.iVar atIndex:self.iVar.index];
[iVar release];
```

Or you could use a temporary variable.